# Как правильно настроить VDS сервер nginx ubuntu 14 или 16 для работы на NODEJS

Tags: node.js, nginx, веб-сервер

Господа, начав изучение NodeJs, столкнулся с недопониманием некоторых моментов по настройке сервера Nginx. Вот площадка [тут](https://sweb.ru/). Кстати не рекомендую... Тормозит очень. Поковырявшись в поисковиках, нашел статью, ничего интересного, но были хорошие ссылки.

1. [Это ссылка по установке NVM](https://github.com/creationix/nvm)
2. [Это ссылка по установке Аjenti панели](http://support.ajenti.org/forums/5-kb/topics/1121-installing-on-ubuntu/)
3. [Эта ссылка компонентов Аjenti панели](http://support.ajenti.org/forums/5-kb/topics/1130-installing-ajenti-v-on-debianubuntu/)

Начинаю с установки NVM. Потом устанавливаю NodeJs.  Потом устанавливаю Аjenti. Ну а вот тут начинается самое интересное и непонятное. После  действий описанных выше, я перехожу по третьей ссылке и устанавливаю компоненты Аjenti. И пока я не установлю весь список пакетов из третей ссылки, сервер у меня не запускается.

Вот как выглядит сервер

```
    const http = require('http'),
           path = require('path'),
           express = require('express');

      var app = express();

      var server = http.createServer(app);

      app.listen(8008);
      app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));
```

Вот так выглядит  index.html главный

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test-NodeJs</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style/master.css">
    
</head>

<body>
    <div id="wrapper">

    </div>
    <script src="./js/master.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Вот так выглядит структура папок

[image: Структура]

По логике, я устанавливаю из третьей ссылки
Вот эти компоненты:

> ajenti-v (main package)
>
> ajenti-v-nginx (NGINX webserver support)
>
> ajenti-v-nodejs (Node.js support)

И по моей логике сервер должен работать, но увы...
пока я не установлю весь список сервер не запускается
Вопрос в том, что у меня база данных mondodb. На кой мне mysql? Не хочу PHP. Не использую python и ruby. Зачем мне устанавливать весь список?

> ajenti-v (main package)
>
> ajenti-v-mail (Exim and Courier mail)
>
> ajenti-v-mysql (MySQL DB support)
>
> ajenti-v-php-fpm (PHP support via PHP-FPM)
>
> ajenti-v-php7.0-fpm
>
> ajenti-v-ruby-unicorn (Rails support via Unicorn)
>
> ajenti-v-ruby-puma (Rails support via Puma)
>
> ajenti-v-ftp-pureftpd (FTPsupport via PureFTPd)
>
> ajenti-v-nginx (NGINX webserver support)
>
> ajenti-v-python-gunicorn (Python WSGI support via gunicorn)
>
> ajenti-v-nodejs (Node.js support)

Вот скрины Ajenti панели  как она настроена...
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S.  Столько тут наворотил, что потерял уверенность, правильно ли я сформулировал вопрос...

В итоге вопросы такие:  можно ли настроить так сервер , что бы обойтись минимальными пакетами.  Может посоветуйте другую панель и зачем же мне все таки устанавливать весь список пакетов Ajenti и какие ошибки??????

Comment: Любые панели - зло в системе!

Comment: @SeyDee, буду признателен, если подскажешь как обойтись без панели...  Вообще не имею представления, как через консоль по протоколу ssh  настроить все...   Я так понимаю, что бы настроить определенный домен читал с определенной папки скрипты это надо nginx настроить? Представления не имею...  Будь другом или пример покажи или хотя бы скажи, что почитать...

Comment: Примеры...  <br/>
-  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5009324/node-js-nginx-what-now
-  https://gist.github.com/cosbynator/3072833
-  https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: У Вас получилось настроить `nginx`?

Comment: @Дмытрык не так,как хотелось бы...  в приведенном в вопросе примере он у меня и так работал